# .htaccess code for folder>subfolder>subfolder>allfiles.html (or jpg) redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I have tried various combinations and I'm going a bit crazy trying to figure out the .htaccess code to redirect all files in a folder>subfolder>subfolder>allfiles.html (or jpg)redirect

domain.com/portfolio/fashion-beauty/pages/*.*

to

http://myportfolio.smugmug.com

this is the latest I have tried with no luck...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.primary\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/fashion-beauty/pages/(.*) $ http://myportfolio.smugmug.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What URLs do you want to rewrite to what path or file ? Also format your code for better lisibility.

Comment: the actual url to where files were that need to redirect is http://www.fotolook.com/portfolio/Las-Vegas-Weddings/slides/las-vegas-wedding-photos-087.html (I need all files in the folder to redirect) and they need to redirect to this folder in smugmug: http://christine-copeland-makeup.smugmug.com/Las-Vegas-Weddings/

Answer (score 0):

You have a minor mistake in your URI matching regex, try this code in the root `.htaccess` of `fotolook.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.fotolook\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ http://christine-copeland-makeup.smugmug.com/Las-Vegas-Weddings/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: should the word primary contain the domain name?

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.primary\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/Brides-Weddings-Events/slides/(.*)$ http://christine-copeland-makeup.smugmug.com/Las-Vegas-Weddings/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: I thought it was formatted? sorry.. every time I hit return it submits .. not sure hwo to format here

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews  
    RewriteEngine On  

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.primary\.com$  [NC]  
    RewriteRule ^portfolio/Brides-Weddings-Events/slides/(.*)$     http://christine-copeland-makeup.smugmug.com/Las-Vegas-Weddings/$1 [R=301,NC,L]  tried to format this correctly...

Comment: You need to put your code by editing your question (not in comments)

Comment: Thank you very much for telling me how to edit I appreciate that -- first time here ;-)  I tried your code update and it works at the portfolio/ level but it still didn't work on the sub directories or the actual files I am trying to redirect. I have people hitting on the old files and want to redirect them to the new portfolio...I tried all kinds of combinations in cpanel and nothing I have tried worked

Comment: Do you want to redirect all `/portfolio/*` URLs to new site?

Comment: yes that would work if that is the best I can get it. That at least would elimnate the 404s. However there are a variety of subfolders for different jobs and ideally I want them to go to a similarly named subfolder on the target domain... I figure if I can get one to work I can just change out the names and set them all to then redirect correctly. If you can come up with something I am happy to donate $30 by paypal for your effort.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.. and that is closer... but..

it now gets me to the smugmug domain but it also appends the subfolder1>subfolder2>*.* onto the smugmug domain and those folders do not exist on the smugmug domain, so I get a 404 file not found on the smugmug domain, I actually would like that it would go to smugmug>newfolder> and pickup the index file in the newfolder in smugmug. Thank you for your effort I am ready to give up... I made a post also on Webhosting talk and getting no luck there either

Comment: ok check another update to my answer. I will of offline for couple of hours and check back your comment later.

Comment: No it didn't redirect unless I took off the filename and then it takes me here: http://christine-copeland-makeup.smugmug.com/Las-Vegas-Weddings/slides/ if there was a way to get rid of the slides folder so it goes to: http://christine-copeland-makeup.smugmug.com/Las-Vegas-Weddings/ that would work for me... I'm out now til morning... thank you

Comment: see updated answer, It will take you to `http://christine-copeland-makeup.smugmug.com/Las-Vegas-Weddings/` (**make sure to test in a new browser**)

Comment: I just tried with a fresh browser and it is working!  thank you so much.  Email me through the contact form and I will Paypal you for your trouble.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're most welcome, so glad it worked out. No I don't want to make money on this forum, this is just for helping community. You should first mark this answer as accepted and if you really want to you can write something on my LinkedIn recommendation.